# What does the name "m4" mean in m4 macro processor?

Tags: m4

I am so curious about the name "m4", what does "m" and "4" mean?

Comment: I had removed the linux and gnu tags because the question has nothing to do with either linux or gnu. It's a UNIX question. m4 is available on all unix-like systems and long before Linux ever came to be.

Comment: OK, Thanks for correction, I modified the question title, removed the word GNU.

Answer (score 5):

[Because it's the next version from the m3 processor.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_(computer_language))

> The language was designed by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie for
>   the original versions of UNIX. **It is an extension of an earlier
>   macro processor m3**, written by Ritchie for the AP-3 minicomputer.

Comment: thanks. but what does m3 mean? "m" and "3" is short for what?

Comment: @user6329088 m is for macro processor. 3 is the version number. In the days of its creation, programs were given as short a name as possible to preserve memory and disk space as both were expensive and in short supply.